# How to mock ngrx action in Angular component?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner, ngrx, effects

//component code on init function

```
this.rootStore.dispatch(new action1());
```

In the effects I have calling the 'action1Success'

I have pipe for action1Success and subscribe function in component

//component code

```
this.actionListener$.pipe( ofType(  MyactionTypes.action1Success)).subscribe((success: SuccessObj) => { });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **provideMockActions**

```
import { provideMockActions } from '@ngrx/effects/testing';
...
describe('RouterHistoryEffects', () => {
  let actions: ReplaySubject<any>;
  let effects: YourEffects;

  beforeEach(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      provideMockActions(() => actions)
    ]
  });
 ....
```

and your test should be something like this

```
// dispatch your action

(actions$ as ReplaySubject).next({ type: '[Users] Get Users' })

// subscribe to the Effect stream
effects.getUsers$.subscribe(action => {
 expect(action).toEqual({
  type: '[Users API] action1Success',
  users: [...],
});
});
```

Comment: I need to mock action in component.