# How to write jasmine unit test mocking ngrx action in Angular component?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ngrx

Here is my sample code:

```
import { Actions, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

constructor(private actions$: Actions) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(orderPlacedSuccessAction),
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
  )
  .subscribe((result) => {
    this.somethingChanged = true;
    this.updateSomething();   
  });
}
```

I have checked this answer however it is not valuable to me. Link: [How to mock ngrx action in Angular component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102516/how-to-mock-ngrx-action-in-angular-component)

Comment: did you read https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/testing ?

Comment: @serrulien The link you provided contains examples for the effects file. I need to mock the component file.